# Cancel order with Magento's Free Payment Method

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, payment-methods

I have a few orders in the system which were placed using Magento's Free ( No Payment Required ) method but I want to try cancel them.

How do you go about cancelling an order with this payment method? There is no option in the backend and you can't credit memo something with R0 value.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have had this problem as well and we are on Magento CE 1.5.0.1.  It looks like it's been an issue for a while.  Please post any solutions you find!

Comment: Did you try to cancel the invoice (not the order!) Did you try to cancel the order? If not, maybe just create the shipping, then the order is complete?

Answer (score 1):

If the payment method has been setup to go directly into the status "processing" then you will not be able to cancel the order as orders that have an invoice cannot be cancelled via the admin section.

You can check your settings via `System->Configuration->Sales->Payment Methods`

Here under the tab `Zero Subtotal Checkout` you can assign if the invoice is setup and which status the order will be put into.

[image]